# Error: Could not resolve host: github.com during clone operation

Tags: git, github, odoo

When I tried to HTTPS clone Odoo modules from git-hub, I got the following error message:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/odoomrp/odoomrp-wip.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

This is my ubuntu command:

```
git clone https://github.com/odoomrp/odoomrp-wip.git
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like you are running Ubuntu inside a VM, and you don't have network configured correctly for the VM.  This problem is completely unrelated to git.

Comment: @SvenMarnach You are most likely right. When I ping github.com or even google.com in Windows 7, I get "Request timed out" messages. I tried to create a custom inbound rule, in Windows Firewall, for ICMPv4 and ICMPv6 to allow in, but it didn't help.

Comment: You need to configure the VM correctly, in the UI of whatever virtualization software you are using.

Comment: @SvenMarnach If I am not mistaken, if Windows 7 (host) cannot see the website, then VM cannot see it either.

Comment: Nash: You are right -- I misread your preious comment.  If you have networking problems on your host, you need to fix that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VM was not connected to network adapter. Right clicking on the network icon of the VM and selecting Connect Network Adapter resolved the issue.